# Is there a way to fix this Windows boot issue?

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr

I have a dual-boot system (Windows/Linux) and recently started having trouble booting into Windows. Probably an MBR problem. I can use a GRUB2 bootable CD to access Windows, and Linux boots just fine. However, when I use the Windows install disc it cannot find my install of Windows to try and repair. I scoured the Internet and tried things like using bootrec, I tried startup repair three times in a row (that was a popular solution), reloading SATA drivers, etc. and nothing worked.

First, does anyone have any suggestions?

Second, since I CAN get into my Windows install using the GRUB2 CD, could I make a recovery disc of Windows and load that?

Feedback and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Boot off of the Windows install CD and start the Recovery console. From there you issue the `fixmbr` command.

Comment: I would suggest a more informative question title in the future, like "Windows Boot disk fails to find partition" instead.

Comment: I have used fixmbr and it says it was successful, but still unable to boot. fixboot returns "The volume does not contain a recognized file system." What I'm not understanding is why I can boot from a GRUB2 boot disk, but it seems Windows cannot find itself to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your Windows 7 installation with following commands booted from recovery CD/DVD:

1. bootsect /nt60 all /mbr
2. bcdboot c:\windows

Drive c: is assumed to be Windows partition, if not change drive letter.

Later when you have fixed Windows booting you can rearrange dual booting Linux using the method described in [Dual boot Windows 7 and Linux/UNIX](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html). It is based on Windows boot manager + chain loading grub first stage to dual boot Window and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Solution at from ArtBIT about disconnecting other drives worked for me:

[WIndows 7 cannot boot - bootrec reports FS not found or corrupt](https://superuser.com/questions/241739/windows-7-cannot-boot-bootrec-reports-fs-not-found-or-corrupt)