# Windows 10 boot\bcd not found error 0x000000f

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader, boot-partition, bcdboot

I made C drive as Active in disk management; later I rebooted the system it gave me error saying that "windows cannot find boot\bcd due to software\hardware changes,use windows disk to repair the system"..

I tried to repair the system by using the live OS (by opening cmd in repair PC option) and tried to recover the BCD ,but it says 'BCD not found in the specified directory'.

Is there any other  method to recover pc? If it's not there then how can I safely recover my PC?

I am not using dual boot.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/294633/12591